# OpenVPN Allow Servers to talk to VPN Clients

Tags: openvpn, subnet, gateway, route, amazon-vpc

I have setup a VPC in Amazon with 2 subnets. The public subnet has a ip range of 10.0.0.XXX and a private subnet with a ip range of 10.0.1.XXX my OpenVPN sits on 10.0.0.100 and hands out ip from the 5.5.0.XXX range

Everything works fine and my VPN clients can connect in and talk to the Servers in the Private subnet with out a problem.

But how do I allow for the servers to be able to talk back to the VPN clients that have a 5.5.0.XXX ip address ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have 2 /24 subnets there probably is a gateway between them. Try to add this route on the gateway:

`ip route add 5.5.0.0/24 via 10.0.0.100`

Comment: Thank you for the replay pupkinsen, Yes there is a gateway that Amazon automatically defines but I don't believe you can connect in and add routes to it. I know in the VPC you can add routes so I wonder if I can add the route there ?

Answer (score 0):

Found that I needed to add the extra subnet in to routing rules in the VPC control panel and then add a rule on the VPN security group to allow traffic from the EC2 instance in the private subnet